# cannot remove gap between bars from React vis graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-vis

I have the following:

```
<XYPlot xType="ordinal" width={300} height={300} xDistance={0}>
    <VerticalGridLines />
    <HorizontalGridLines />
    <XAxis />
    <VerticalBarSeries className="vertical-bar-series-example" data={greenData} />
    <LabelSeries data={labelData} getLabel={d => d.y} />
</XYPlot>
```

and some mocked data like so:

```
const greenData = [
    {x: 34, y: 200},
    {x: 35, y: 220},
    {x: 36, y: 240},
    {x: 37, y: 260},
    {x: 38, y: 280},
    {x: 39, y: 300}
];

const labelData = greenData.map((d, idx) => ({
  x: Math.max(greenData[idx].x),
  y: d.y
}));
```

however I cannot find a solution to remove the gap between bars:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a `VerticalBarSeries` which will produce a bar graph (with spacing between each bar). If you're looking for a histogram, which will not have spacing between each bar. You need to use `VerticalRectSeries` to create the histogram.

[histograms documentation](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/master/showcase/plot/stacked-histogram.js)

```
<XYPlot xType="ordinal" width={300} height={300}>
    <VerticalGridLines />
    <HorizontalGridLines />
    <XAxis />
    <VerticalRectSeries className="vertical-bar-series-example" data={greenData} />
    <LabelSeries data={labelData} getLabel={d => d.y} />
</XYPlot>
```